# Windows MySQL not starting despite entering correct password. No error showing. Application closing instantly

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, mysql-connector

I noticed the problem when I tried using Python's MySQL connector to complete a few school assignments.

I used correct syntax, here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
connector_obj=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='deven')
my_cursor=connector_obj.cursor()
my_cursor.execute('show databases')
print(my_cursor)
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py in open_connection(self)
    573             self.sock.settimeout(self._connection_timeout)
--> 574             self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
    575         except IOError as err:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\...\CS_Board_SQP_Codes.py in 
      108 import mysql.connector
----> 109 connector_obj=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='deven')
      110 my_cursor=connector_obj.cursor()
      111 my_cursor.execute('show databases')
      112 print(my_cursor)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py in connect(*args, **kwargs)
    271     if HAVE_CEXT and not use_pure:
    272         return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
--> 273     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    274 Connect = connect  # pylint: disable=C0103
    275 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    105         if kwargs:
    106             try:
--> 107                 self.connect(**kwargs)
    108             except:
    109                 # Tidy-up underlying socket on failure

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py in connect(self, **kwargs)
   1001 
   1002         self.disconnect()
-> 1003         self._open_connection()
   1004         # Server does not allow to run any other statement different from ALTER
   1005         # when user's password has been expired.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py in _open_connection(self)
    348         self._socket = self._get_connection()
    349         try:
--> 350             self._socket.open_connection()
    351             self._do_handshake()
    352             self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py in open_connection(self)
    574             self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
    575         except IOError as err:
--> 576             raise errors.InterfaceError(
    577                 errno=2003, values=(
    578                     self.server_host,

InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

I tried opening MySQL manually to see if it works. I entered the correct password, it stayed there for a couple of seconds and then the window closed.

For those who prefer watching a video:
[Click Here to watch the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vE8IOuQZqkozZpRcsWGU7OWL0wVoDxpH/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

which sql connector have you installed?

try deleting current installed one and install again using below mentioned command:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```